# Test with many variables: I looking for quick method to introduce each variable in the test

Tags: python, loops, variables, scipy, kruskals-algorithm

I have some data and I need to compare the average but I am looking for quick method to introduce each sample in the test.

```
from scipy import stats

my_variables = ["a","b","c"]
my_variables[0] = [1,2,3]
my_variables[1] = [0,1,2]
my_variables[2] = [2,3,4]

Kruskal_Wallis_test= stats.kruskal(my_variables[0], my_variables[1], my_variables[2])
```

Would be it possible doing something like this?

```
Kruskal_Wallis_test= stats.kruskal(my_variables)
```

Comment: Do you mean `stats.kruskal(*my_variables)`?

Comment: use * to unpack list, **Suggestion**  You can use append function to add elements to you list variable rather then hardcode replacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The `*` is used to unpack the argument list when the function is called, in this case it upacks your `my_variables` list.

Here is how you should use `*` operator in your code,

```
Kruskal_Wallis_test = stats.kruskal(*my_variables)
```

which is identical to calling,

```
Kruskal_Wallis_test= stats.kruskal(my_variables[0], my_variables[1], my_variables[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
Kruskal_Wallis_test = stats.kruskal(*my_variables)
```

It uses * to unpack the list.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `*` to unpack your list variable**

```
from scipy import stats

my_variables = list()
my_variables.append([1,2,3])
my_variables.append([0,1,2])
my_variables.append([2,3,4])

Kruskal_Wallis_test= stats.kruskal(*my_variables)

print(Kruskal_Wallis_test)
```

**Response**
KruskalResult(statistic=3.9532163742690107, pvalue=0.13853833742651062)